# use the #include <windows.h> make my console crash on windows 10

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a program which includes `<windows.h>` and it works in computers that run windows 7 or 8, but crashes in a computer that runs windows 10. Can you help me?
This is the part of the code that makes my console crash:

```
 #include <cstdlib>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <conio.h>
 #include <ctime>
 #include <windows.h>

 using namespace std;

 void sposta_tu(posizione pos, char cosa){
      HANDLE handle = GetStdHandle ( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE );
      COORD coordinate = {pos.y,pos.x};
      FillConsoleOutputCharacter ( handle, cosa ,1, coordinate, 0 );
 }
 void ellimina_tu(posizione pos){
      HANDLE handle = GetStdHandle ( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE );
      COORD coordinate = {pos.y,pos.x};
      FillConsoleOutputCharacter ( handle,' ',1, coordinate, 0 );
 }
```

Comment: Last parameter has a pointer type, but you specify `0`, which is an integer expression. Change your compiler settings so the warning level is higher - this will result in compiler emitting a proper warning. They are quite helpful in eliminating such errors.

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek That's not an issue with types. The failure would be the same with a pointer type that equals null.

Answer (score 2):

```
BOOL WINAPI FillConsoleOutputCharacter(
  _In_  HANDLE  hConsoleOutput,
  _In_  TCHAR   cCharacter,
  _In_  DWORD   nLength,
  _In_  COORD   dwWriteCoord,
  _Out_ LPDWORD lpNumberOfCharsWritten
);
```

Last parameter is out parameter, you can't pass 0.

```
DWORD numberOfCharsWritten;
FillConsoleOutputCharacter(handle, ' ', 1, coordinate, &numberOfCharsWritten);
```

Comment: It does not change anything. The program crash in any case. I'desperate, please help me

Comment: @matteocamillo you need to show the error and your new functions